# Dismiss banner notification view in iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications, banner

While receiving push notification in my app, it shouldn’t be shown anywhere in iPhone(banner) but it should receive to fetch data alone. Is it possible to do.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: When you create the push to send, do you include an @"alert" key in the payload dictionary?

Comment: thanks for your reply, yes i had set "alert"

Comment: If i omitting @"alert", it will send APNs data?

Comment: You can send other items in the payload dictionary under your own key.  Or you can set the @"content-available" key to trigger a background fetch (if you have registered for background fetch and the user agrees to allowing it)

Answer (score 0):

Try omitting the @"alert" key from the payload dictionary when you create the push to send.

From https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html  regarding the alert key: If this property is included, the system displays a standard alert. You may specify a string as the value of alert or a dictionary as its value. If you specify a string, it becomes the message text of an alert with two buttons: Close and View. If the user taps View, the app is launched.
Alternatively, you can specify a dictionary as the value of alert.

Comment: If i omitting @"alert", it will send APNs data?

Comment: see my comment above :)